# how can I connect my client to EC2?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I am a beginner with EC2, also with everything on mysql, asp, etc.

I am now trying to figure out how to connect my client side with ec2 instance, which mysql is running on.

is it possible to use php or asp on the client side, and make a request to ec2 my sql and return values i want.

is there an example of that?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Define "client side"? The user's browser? Or your own server? PHP/ASP aren't "client side". For latency reasons, you'd be best running PHP/ASP within EC2 if your database is going to be hosted there.

Comment: for client side，I mean the user's browser. so PHP/ASP is supposed to run on the server, right? then how can i connect browser request to ec2? thanks.

Comment: Yes, PHP/ASP run on the server. EC2 is just another way of hosting a server. You'd point a domain name at the EC2 server just like you'd point a domain name at any other server, or you can use the temporary domain name Amazon assigns for you. For example: http://ec2-50-19-212-110.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the public dns name of your ec2. Do it like you normally would if you had a local host, just change the ipaddress/dns name.

Comment: You also have to allow traffic to the EC2 instance on the right ports.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to enable encryption in MySQL, otherwise all your data will be sent over the Internet in the clear! Not a good idea...